# JAVA POI code to Read Text box values from Excel (xlsx)

Tags: java, excel-2010

I'm able to read the excel cell values via POI library but the excel file contains new text boxes (shapes) with values.
Some big texts like description etc are put in a text box (shapes) and Im stuck to read them. 
Could someone please help me with the java code to read the text in shapes from a excel file (xlsx format)? Thanks and appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you paste your code here and tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: You're "able to read the excel". How? How do you expect us to help you, when we don't know what library, if any, you're using?

Comment: Please paste your poi code for reading files, i can suggest you to use jxl its much simpler than poi just the constraint is you have to use 97-2003 xls sheets. But if you have xlsx sheets you can convert it to xls using vbs to make it work

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
XSSFDrawing pat = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
            // @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            if (pat != null){

                List<XSSFShape> children = pat.getShapes();

                Iterator<XSSFShape> it = children.iterator(); 

             while(it.hasNext()) {           
                 XSSFShape shape = (XSSFShape)it.next();
                 if (shape instanceof XSSFSimpleShape){
                     XSSFSimpleShape textbox = (XSSFSimpleShape)shape;
                   String str = textbox.getText();
                   System.out.println("String: " + str);
                   System.out.println("String length: " + str.length());
                 };
             }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone..i found the solution and it worked for xls and not for xlsx. i'm able to read the text from text box(shapes).

```
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream("test.xls");
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    //get the patriarch
    HSSFPatriarch pat = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();

    HSSFClientAnchor a = new HSSFClientAnchor(0,0,10,50,(short)1,0,(short)1,0);
    List child = pat.getChildren();
    String str;
    int i=0;
    Iterator iCount = child.iterator(); 
    while(iCount.hasNext()) {
        HSSFShape shape = (HSSFShape)iCount.next();

        if (shape instanceof HSSFTextbox){
            HSSFTextbox textbox = (HSSFTextbox)shape;
            HSSFRichTextString richString = textbox.getString();
            str = richString.getString();
            System.out.println("String: \n" + str);
            System.out.println("String length: " + str.length());
        }
        i++;
        System.out.print("\n i =" +i);
    }
```

---